# How to use Libgit2Sharp on Mono/MacOsX?

Tags: c#, mono, libgit2sharp

I am using Xamarin Studio 5.7 with Mono 3.12 on OSX 10.9.5. Using NuGet I downloaded the libgit2sharp library. I am able to use the classes when writing the code, there are no compiler errors. However at run time I get the following error:

`Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods ---> System.DllNotFoundException: git2-91fa31f
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods:git_threads_init ()
  at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods+LibraryLifetimeObject..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_repository_open (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at LibGit2Sharp.Repository..ctor (System.String path, LibGit2Sharp.RepositoryOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods ---> System.DllNotFoundException: git2-91fa31f
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods:git_threads_init ()
  at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods+LibraryLifetimeObject..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_repository_open (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at LibGit2Sharp.Repository..ctor (System.String path, LibGit2Sharp.RepositoryOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0`

It seems to be complaining that it cannot find the `git2-91fa31f` dll but when I look in the packages folder I can see that that dll does exist.

Has anyone seen this before or know what I can do to fix it?

UPDATE

I followed @nulltoken's instructions and downloaded the libgit2 source. Built it using `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=RelWithDebInfo -DBUILD_CLAR:BOOL=OFF -DUSE_SSH=OFF -DENABLE_TRACE=ON -DLIBGIT2_FILENAME=git2-91fa31f -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES="i386;x86_64" ..` then `cmake --build .`

This produced a file called `libgit2-91fa31f.dylib`. I placed this file in the `bin/Debug` directory where the exe of my project is and where `LibGit2Sharp.dll` is. However now when I run the program I get the following:

`Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods ---> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: git_threads_init
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods:git_threads_init ()
  at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods+LibraryLifetimeObject..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_repository_open (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at LibGit2Sharp.Repository..ctor (System.String path, LibGit2Sharp.RepositoryOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods ---> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: git_threads_init
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods:git_threads_init ()
  at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods+LibraryLifetimeObject..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_repository_open (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at LibGit2Sharp.Repository..ctor (System.String path, LibGit2Sharp.RepositoryOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0`

I have a feeling I messed up the cmake part. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LibGit2Sharp is a .Net binding to the native libgit2 library.

The project ensures that all the tests run on Win 32/64, Linux and MacOsX through the use of continuous integration servers (**[Travis](https://travis-ci.org/libgit2/libgit2sharp)** and **[AppVeyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/libgit2/libgit2sharp)**).

However, currently the LibGit2Sharp NuGet package only contains the Windows native compiled binaries and, as such, won't be usable as-is on Linux/MacOsX. In order to use LibGit2Sharp in those environments, you'd have to build libgit2 by yourself.

In order to make this happen, you'll need **[CMake](http://www.cmake.org/)**.

You can get some inspiration from the **[build.libgit2sharp.sh script](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/build.libgit2sharp.sh)** that's used by the CI servers.

In this **[Issue](https://github.com/ParticularLabs/GitVersion/issues/264#issuecomment-57610456)**, Therzork, a Xamariner (and a LibGit2sharp core contributor), shares some guidance regarding building on MacOsX.

### Update

> I have a feeling I messed up the cmake part. Is that correct?

I think the got the CMake part is just fine. The exception raised is `System.EntryPointNotFoundException`. This means that LibGit2Sharp tries to call a method from libgit2 which either doesn't exist or whose signature (number of parameters, types, ...) doesn't match what's exposed.

Indeed, each version of LibGit2Sharp works against a specific version of libgit2. The libgit2 abbreviated commit sha is used to exactly which version of libgit2 is expected.

Version v0.20.1 expects to work against a compiled version of libgit2 as it was in commit 91fa3af (For each LibGit2sharp commit, you can check the expected libgit2 version by taking a look at the libgit2 submodule (for instance, **[v0.20.1](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/tree/v0.20.1)**)).

My guess would be that you're actually building a different libigt2 commit (probably the latest one). In order to build commit 91fa31f, run the following git command lines in a shell:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2
$ cd libgit2
$ git checkout 91fa31f
```

Then run your CMake magic. The produced binary should now match LibGit2Sharp expectations.

Comment: Where do I need to put the libgit2  binary then? Also, is libgit2 not part of what is installed when you install git?

Comment: *"is libgit2 not part of what is installed when you install git?"* -> No. This may be a good fit for a different question, though.

Comment: *"Where do I need to put the libgit2 binary then?"* -> An easy way, as stated by Therzork in the last link, is : "Make sure the libgit2 native livrary binaries are side-by-side with the libgit2sharp DLLs so you don't have to mess with library resolver path settings."

Comment: thank you for the link. I have followed the instructions but still had issues. I updated my post with my results. Thank you for your help, I am coming from a Windows C# world so beyond using NuGet I am bad with getting dlls to work.

Answer (score 0):

libgit2sharp requires libgit2 installed. Have you installed that yet?

https://libgit2.github.com